# Reload a web page in Webview from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I know this is a duplication question and i have been doing a lot of research about this but still not able to find the answer.

I am developing a web page and open this url using Android WebView. So, I am trying to create a button to reload the URL. using :

```
location.reload(true)
```

But its not working. Is there anyone has solution ? Thanks

// Update

I am not able to edit the app that has the webView. Just using javascript.

// Update

Hmmm Its weird. Its working now without changing anything in my code. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to refresh WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview)

Comment: @jeprubio I am not able to edit the webView. The WebView is coming from a 3rd party application. i am just using javascript and load it into the webview. If that make senses to you.

Comment: @daniel8x I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979010/reloading-a-webview-with-a-javascript-call-from-a-loaded-web-page) will help using javascript

Comment: hmmm. It's weird. I have not change anything. and everything is working now. I dont know why ...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
myWebViewID.loadUrl("REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_URL");
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am not able to edit the webView. just using javascript.